# How do I use ServiceWorker without a separate JS file?

Tags: service-worker

We create service workers by

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js', { scope: '/' });
```

We can create new `Workers` without an external file like this,

```js
var worker = function() { console.log('worker called'); };
var blob = new Blob( [ '(' , worker.toString() , ')()' ], {
    type: 'application/javascript'
});
var bloburl = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
var w = new Worker(bloburl);
```

With the approach of using blob to create ServiceWorkers, we will get a `Security Error` as the bloburl would be `blob:chrome-extension...`, and the origin won't be supported by Service Workers.

Is it possible to create a service worker without external file and use the scope as `/` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would strongly recommend not trying to find a way around the requirement that the service worker implementation code live in a standalone file. There's a very important of the service worker lifecycle, [updates](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#update-algorithm), that relies on your browser being able to fetch your registered service worker JavaScript resource periodically and do a byte-for-byte comparison to see if anything has changed.

If something has changed in your service worker code, then the new code will be considered the `installing` service worker, and the old service worker code will eventually be considered the `redundant` service worker as soon as all pages that have the old code registered and unloaded/closed.

While a bit difficult to wrap your head around at first, understanding and making use of the different service worker lifecycle states/events are important if you're concerned about cache management. If it weren't for this update logic, once you registered a service worker for a given scope once, it would never give up control, and you'd be stuck if you had a bug in your code/needed to add new functionality.

Comment: Maybe encoding the whole serviceWorker in a BASE64 string ?

Comment: I have tried all the possible ways, the only with worked was using `filesystem:` urls but it stopped working. It's sad because it assumes what Jeff said and strictly denies developers from creating JavaScript based "Internet Explorer 6" i.e.: applications without auto-update. Come on, it's 2015 and Tor doesn't have auto-update. Instead it haves a manual one (is it safer? I don't know). Why we can't do the same in JS? User friendly? I unsure about this: disabling Firefox extension and Android app auto-update is just a checkbox.

Answer (score 5):

One hacky way is to use the the same javascript file understand the context and act as a ServiceWorker as well as the one calling it.

#### HTML

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

#### main.js

```
if(!this.document) {
    self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
        console.log('service worker installation');
    });
} else {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('main.js')
}
```

To prevent maintaining this as a big file `main.js`, we could use,

```
if(!this.document) {
    //service worker js
    importScripts('sw.js');
else {
    //loadscript document.js by injecting a script tag
}
```

But it might come back to using a separate `sw.js` file for service worker to be a better solution. This would be helpful if one'd want a single entry point to the scripts.

Comment: I would not recommend this approach, as it would defeat the logic that's in place to trigger the `update` flow when the service worker's code changes.

Comment: @jeff-posnick can you clarify (beyond your accepted answer) how this would defeat the logic? It appears ServiceWorker would be re-installed whenever `main.js` was edited, which would would make it possible to extraneously trigger a re-install but wouldn't prevent updates.