# Javascrip service worker blob

Tags: javascript, blob, service-worker

I am trying to download a file in a service worker. The file came from a blob.

I already know that i can download a blob by doing this

```
var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var blobURL = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob, { type: "octet/stream" });
```

or by using something like FileSaver.js

But today, i am trying to "render" the bytes array of the blob in the page and force the browser to download the document.

Why ?
I am trying to do that because, some browser that i am trying to reach do not support url like "blob:https:......"

So i try to find a way to render the bytearrays of my blob directly in javascript.

I know that i can push headers with worker, but not sure that is the right strategie.

I also try something like that

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', obj.URL, false);
      xhr.overrideMimeType("application/octet-stream");
      //xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/octet-stream");
      xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
      xhr.onload = function (e) {

        self.Response(xhr.response);
        //if (this.status == 200) {
        //  var myBlob = this.response;
        //  // myBlob is now the blob that the object URL pointed to.
        //}
      };
      xhr.send();
```

In my worker.js

ps: Please avoid to told me, send you base64 blob content to your server and send back the file to the browser, i would like to find a pure javascript solution.

Is it possible ?

Comment: I personally don't have any blob:// request experience.
But I would point out you should update the code from XMLHttpRequest to use the Fetch API. 
I don't know if that will change things for you or not, but you should at least use the modern API :)
The fetch Response object has a blob() helper method and that might be helpful in this case. It is designed for binary response bodies.

Comment: `blob:https:` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Bergi, make any sense ? href="blob:https://www.youwebsite.com/98765456765" the url of a blob look like that ... what did not make any sense ?

Comment: @ChrisLove, yes thanks, i have also test the fetch method ... but i reveived a blob. Did you know if we can force a download with the fetch ?

Comment: Is it coming from another domain? If so then you have an opaque response and you cannot access the bits directly. You can still load the bits from an image tag (example) via the src property. But you can't manipulate the bits.
Also note: opaque responses require more space to cache, like 8MB minimum.

Comment: @CédricBoivin I doesn't make sense to have two schemes in a URI. You can use only one protocol. Btw, have a look at [How do I use ServiceWorker without a separate JS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27986290/1048572), [this authoritative Github comment](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/578#issuecomment-66066294), and [How to use inline service worker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31515426/1048572), which all agree on that what you are trying to do is not possible.

Comment: @Bergi, i understand your point, but that is not my call ... when you do that urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob, { type: "octet/stream" }); the URL we received it's formatted like that blob:https://thedomainenamecom ... I wish it were different, but I didn't choose the navigators' approach

Comment: @ChrisLove no, it's came from same domain. Maybe the service worker will not be the good approach