# PWA service worker without external JS file

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker

Is it possible to include sw.js into index.html?
Or is it possible to register a service worker for https://test.example.com from https://test.com ? if yes then how?
CORS - no problem.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#46a546" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="pwa.json">
    <script>
    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
        self.addEventListener("load", async () => {
            const container = navigator.serviceWorker;
            if (container.controller === null) {
                const reg = await container.register("sw.js");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

sw.js

```
'use strict';
const CACHE_STATIC = 'static-cache-v1';

function hndlEventInstall(evt) {
    async function cacheStaticFiles() {
        const files = [
            'icon.png',
        ];
        const cacheStat = await caches.open(CACHE_STATIC);
        await Promise.all(
            files.map(function (url) {
                return cacheStat.add(url).catch(function (reason) {
                    console.log(`'${url}' failed: ${String(reason)}`);
                });
            })
        );
    }

    evt.waitUntil(cacheStaticFiles());
}

function hndlEventFetch(evt) {
    async function getFromCache() {
        const cache = await self.caches.open(CACHE_STATIC);
        const cachedResponse = await cache.match(evt.request);
        if (cachedResponse) {
            return cachedResponse;
        }
        const resp = await fetch(evt.request);
        await cache.put(evt.request, resp.clone());
        return resp;
    }

    evt.respondWith(getFromCache());
}

self.addEventListener('install', hndlEventInstall);
self.addEventListener('fetch', hndlEventFetch);
```

Is it possible to create a service worker for PWA without external file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use ServiceWorker without a separate JS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986290/how-do-i-use-serviceworker-without-a-separate-js-file)

Comment: From time to time this arises as request towards W3C: https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/578 (closed, same age as the linked post), https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1642 (this one is 2 years old, but isn't very active).